# How to save the name of a file from the directory as a key of the dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a directory(human_image_dir) with images in the .jpg format. I would like to traverse through each image and add the name of the image file as the key of a dictionary and score as a value.
But I am not sure about the code I have written. I would appreciate your help. 
I have tried the following code:

```
score_dict = {}

obj1_feature = feature.calcFeature(current_human_image)
for image in self.human_image_dir:
      obj2_feature = feature.calcFeature(image)
      score = np.score = np.linalg.norm(obj1_feature - obj2_feature)
      if score < self.threshold:
            score_dict["key"] = "image"
            score_dict["value"] = score
```

Expected output :

```
score_dict = {"image": score }
```

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: Don't you get any output? Or are you just getting the wrong output? 
`score_dict["image"] = score`

Comment: @deedub I have just started writing the module. It depends on the other modules. So I have not tried it yet.

Comment: But you say in your post "_I have tried the following code_"

Comment: What's wrong with the documentation ? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use os for listing all files in a directory, and then just use the name from os as the key when inserting new values into the dictionary.

You also need to read the file into memory, where you could use matplotlib.image

```
import os, sys
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

score_dict = {}

for image in os.listdir(self.human_image_dir):
    img = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(self.human_image_dir,image))
    obj2_feature = feature.calcFeature(img)
    score = np.score = np.linalg.norm(obj1_feature - obj2_feature)
    if score < self.threshold:
        score_dict[image] = score
```

Comment: this image in a for loop will give me name of the file?

Comment: Yes, the os.listdir is only for listing all the names in the directory, so I added some code for reading the image into memory itself as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry to ask you one more question. If I run this code in a function will this dictionary be updated? or I need to add update function. Sorry I do not have the required parameters to check it by myself

Comment: No problem, don't you have python on your computer? Just running the script with any data could help you when testing out new implementations.   
I'm guessing you will you add it to self as well?